# postgresql calculate percentage of sum

Tags: postgresql

Am currently running some queries with table columns:
`unit_cost_cents, quantity_submitted, quantity_accepted`

I would like to get percent of COST and percent of units.

```
SELECT
  SUM(CAST(unit_cost_cents * quantity_submitted / 100.00 AS MONEY)) AS submitted,
  SUM(CAST(unit_cost_cents * quantity_accepted / 100.00 AS MONEY)) AS accepted,
  accepted / submitted AS percent_dollars_accepted,
  quantity_submitted,
  quantity_accepted,
  quantity_submitted / quantity_accepted AS percent_units_accepted
```

the results are not what is expected.

Comment: What result are you expecting? Where is the rest of your query? Particularly the `GROUP BY`? Also, it is not recommended to use `MONEY` data type. You can use `NUMERIC` in lieu of that.

Answer (score 0):

*answering my own, go ahead and downvote i'm happy with my answer :)*

Have to divide by the sum of each:

```
  SELECT
    (DATE_TRUNC('month', (delivery_window_start::timestamptz - INTERVAL '0 second') AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/UTC') + INTERVAL '0 second') AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/UTC' AS month,
    SUM(CAST(unit_cost_cents * quantity_submitted / 100.00 AS MONEY)) AS "Submitted",
    SUM(CAST(unit_cost_cents * quantity_accepted / 100.00 AS MONEY)) AS "Accepted",
    SUM(CAST(unit_cost_cents * (quantity_submitted - quantity_accepted) / 100.00 AS MONEY)) AS "Not Accepted",
    (SUM(unit_cost_cents * quantity_accepted)::float / SUM(unit_cost_cents * quantity_submitted)::float * 100)::numeric(7,2) AS "Confirmation Rate",
    (SUM(unit_cost_cents * (quantity_submitted - quantity_accepted))::float / SUM(unit_cost_cents * quantity_submitted)::float * 100)::numeric(7,2) AS "Cancellation Rate",
    SUM(quantity_submitted) as "Quantity Submitted",
    SUM(quantity_accepted) as "Quantity Accepted",
    SUM(quantity_submitted - quantity_accepted) as "Quantity Not Accepted",
    (SUM(quantity_accepted)::decimal / SUM(quantity_submitted)::decimal * 100)::numeric(7,2) as "Confirmation Rate(Units)",
    (SUM(quantity_submitted - quantity_accepted)::decimal / SUM(quantity_submitted)::decimal * 100)::numeric(7,2) as "Cancellation Rate(Units)"
  FROM account_purchase_orders
  WHERE account_purchase_orders.account_id = #{account_id}
  GROUP BY month
  ORDER BY month ASC
```

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but would you consider this a helpful question & answer for someone who comes across this? You don't provide enough information around what the problem was or how the solution helped.